# Importing stylesheet files in Meteor

Tags: css, import, meteor, stylus

I use Stylus as css preprocessor in Meteor.

Right now I have to suffix all my files with ".import. styl" and then import them manually in one big "app.styl" file.

example files:

```
app.styl
header.import.styl
body.import.styl
```

content of app.styl is:

```
@import header.import.styl
@import body.import.styl
```

Isn't there a more elegant way to do this in Meteor.js?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of downloads from the community on this package

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/stylus

Comment: Yes I use this package. However you still have to manually import all your styl files.